# Does Flink support the Windows OS?

Tags: apache-flink

From this [tutorial](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/setup/flink_on_windows.html), it says we can run flink by `start-local.bat`. But flink 1.1x has no such `.bat` files any more. From recent [tuturial](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.10/getting-started/tutorials/flink_on_windows.html), you have to run flink by **WSL** or **Cygwin**.

Comment: Flink was created to run on linux since most of the clusters have Linux OS. If you want to test in your local Windows machine they advise to use Cygwin to simulate a Linux environment. The `.bat` file is outdated and they removed. So, there is no support to run Flink on windows.

Answer (score 0):

Flink itself runs fine on windows. The only issue is with the scripts used to manage the cluster, and to submit jobs. For that you need some way to run linux shell scripts.

This needn't have much impact; many Flink developers never install a local cluster anyway. You can develop in your IDE just fine, and then use Docker whenever you want to bring up a local environment that resembles production.